# How to send multiple query sets in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a views function in django which returns the data of all influencers. Now I want to add the functionality that a user can make multiple lists and then add those influencers to any of the list created by them. The lists created by the users are displayed in the form of a drop down menu in front of the influencers name. How should I  create the API so that the list created by the users are displayed in front of the influencers.
P.S: I want to create the API without using django rest framework.
This is what I have tried till now:

```
def index(request):
    influencers = Influencer.objects.all()

    influencer_data = serializers.serialize("json",influencers) 
    user_list = UserList.objects.all().filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    user_list = serializers.serialize("json",user_list)
    context = {
        'influencer_data':influencer_data,
        'user_list':user_list,

    }


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context),content_type='application/json')
```

I am getting the result as:

```
{"influencer_data": "[{\"model\": \"influencer_listings.influencer\", \"pk\": 8794, \"fields\": {\"full_name\": \"F A I Z S H A I K H \\ud83c\\udf08\", \"username\": \"mr_faizzz_07\", \"photo\": \"\", \"email_id\": \"\", \"external_url\": \"\ 
.............................
.............................
"user_list": "[{\"model\": \"user_listings.userlist\", \"pk\": 21, \"fields\": {\"user_id\": 5, \"list_name\": \"Campaign 1\"}}, {\"model\": \"user_listings.userlist\", \"pk\": 22, \"fields\": {\"user_id\": 5, \"list_name\": \"Delhi Campaign\"}}]"}
```

The return statement  makes the JSON object returned a string.I want the data to be returned in the JSON format.

Comment: show us what have you tried ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: then try something and then ask if you get any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

def index(request):

    user_list = UserList.objects.all().filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    influencers = Influencer.objects.all()
    queryset = list(chain(user_list, influencers ))
    ser_query = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
    return HttpResponse(ser_query)
```

Do it like this, modify the code to your needs

Comment: I want to send the information from both influencer_data as well as user_list, not just user list.It works fine with just one object but makes the JSON  a string when two objects are passed.

Comment: modified a bit.

Comment: How to do if i'm using class based view?